# I am trying to write a code that takes the sum of each value but also prints each value along the way

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point, sum

I want to take the sum of various equations listed below from 1 to 100. I keep getting an error "float point exception: 8". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double sk1[100]={0};
  double sk2[100]={0};
  double sk3[100]={0};
  double sk4[100]={0};
  for(int i=1;i<101;++i)
  {
    sk1[i-1]+=(1/i)-log(i);
    sk2[i-1]+=1/(i^2);
    sk3[i-1]+=1/(i^3);
    sk4[i-1]+=1/(i^4);
    printf("%e %e %e %e\n",sk1[i-1],sk2[i-1],sk3[i-1],sk4[i-1]);
  }
return 0;
}
```

For example, for sk1, the code would print (1/1)-log(1), then (1/2)-log(2) + the previous value, and so on.

Comment: Also: I suspect OP  does not want integer division with `1/i`.  Perhaps `1.0/i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, and not the power function.

In the 2nd loop, when the cpu is trying to calculate the expression

```
sk2[i-1]+=1/(i^2);
```

it actually try to divide by zero!

**(2 ^ 2) == (00000010 ^ 00000010) == 0**

What you really want to do, is to use `pow`;

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double sk1[100]={0};
  double sk2[100]={0};
  double sk3[100]={0};
  double sk4[100]={0};
  for(int i=1;i<101;++i)
  {
    sk1[i-1]+=(1/i)-log(i);
    sk2[i-1]+=1/pow(i, 2);
    sk3[i-1]+=1/pow(i, 3);
    sk4[i-1]+=1/pow(i, 4);
    printf("%e %e %e %e\n",sk1[i-1],sk2[i-1],sk3[i-1],sk4[i-1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or `sk2[i-1] += pow(i, -2);` etc. But `pow` with small integer exponents is not efficient anyway (not that it matters for such few calculations)

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are using `^`. In C, that is not the power operator, it's the binary XOR operator. Instead, you could use `pow(base, exp)`, which is already included in `math.h`